# Download and installation of Blender 2.93 beta and 3.0 alpha Windows 7 64

Tags: installation

I just downloaded Blender 2.93 (beta Windows 64) and Blender 3.0 (alpha Windows 64).

I copied the files on my linux machine to unzip them. The I copied the unzipped directories back on my Windows 7 64 machine. I even copied 3.0 in the Blender directory nect to the older versions.

When I click on Blender.exe as instructed I got a *"Impossible de démarrer le programme car il manque api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll sur votre ordinateur (...)"*  Which means `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` is missing on my computer. Same thing for both downloads. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Hello, in general this kind of errors are solved by downloading and installing the latest version of Visual C++ libraries. You can download them from the official microsoft website, the file will be called something like vc_redist.x64.exe. Do not ever download this kind of file from a third party site. I'm voting to close this question because it is about a bug, and I'm not sure it relates to Blender. Cheers